# subsetting and reformatting dataframe with uniques characters

Tags: r

How can i reformat and subset a dataframe  with following condition
a) unique(df1$Name)  as rownames, b)unique(df1$ID) ad colnames, c)values for each unique ID for each Name. Note: if a unique name has repeated IDs, select only values for those IDs with highest frequency

df1 <-

```
 Name   ID   value  Frequency
    AA  A-1     0   50
    AA  A-2     1   30
    AA  A-3     0   10
    AA  A-3     1   60
    AA  A-1     1   10
    AA  A-4     1   40
    AA  A-5     1   50
    BB  A-1     0   10
    BB  A-1     1   30
    BB  A-2     1   20
    BB  A-3     0   10
    BB  A-4     1   40
    BB  A-4     0   60
    BB  A-2     1   10
    CC  A-1     0   10
    CC  A-2     0   20
    CC  A-3     1   10
    CC  A-3     1   15
    CC  A-1     1   17
```

expectedoutput <-

```
Name    A-1 A-2 A-3 A-4 A-5
    AA  0   1   1   1   1
    BB  1   1   0   0   
    CC  1   0   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' after filtering out the rows with the highest 'Frequency' for the groups 'Name', 'ID'.  `setDT` converts the `data.frame` to `data.table`, `which.max` gets the numeric index of row with maximum 'Frequency' for the group (`by=list(Name, ID)`).  We subset the dataset based on the index (`.SD`- `Subset of Data.table`), then use `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)#v.1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(df1)[, .SD[which.max(Frequency)], by = list(Name, ID)], 
                            Name~ID, value.var='value', fill=0)
#    Name A-1 A-2 A-3 A-4 A-5
#1:   AA   0   1   1   1   1
#2:   BB   1   1   0   0   0
#3:   CC   1   0   1   0   0
```

Or we can use a similar approach in `dplyr/tidyr` by filtering out the maximum Frequency rows with `slice` after grouping, and then use `spread` to change the format from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 df1 %>% 
    group_by(Name, ID) %>%
    slice(which.max(Frequency)) %>% 
    select(-Frequency) %>% 
    spread(ID, value, fill=0)
```

**NOTE:** Both `spread`, and `dcast` have `fill` option.  By default it is `NA`.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", 
"BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "CC", "CC", 
"CC"), ID = c("A-1", "A-2", "A-3", "A-3", "A-1", "A-4", "A-5", 
"A-1", "A-1", "A-2", "A-3", "A-4", "A-4", "A-2", "A-1", "A-2", 
"A-3", "A-3", "A-1"), value = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Frequency = c(50L, 
30L, 10L, 60L, 10L, 40L, 50L, 10L, 30L, 20L, 10L, 40L, 60L, 10L, 
10L, 20L, 10L, 15L, 17L)), .Names = c("Name", "ID", "value", 
"Frequency"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```